# Airflow: ImportError: No module named configparser

Tags: python, airflow

Environment: Python 2.7.5 & Centos 7

I have successfully installed airflow using:

```
pip install apache-airflow
```

But when I run

`airflow initdb`,

it says:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/airflow", line 21, in <module>
    from airflow import configuration
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from airflow import configuration as conf
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 38, in <module>
    from backports.configparser import ConfigParser
ImportError: No module named configparser
```

What am I missing?

Comment: There is a [JIRA Ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-954) mentioning the same issue. I am not sure whether this fix is available!

Comment: Can you let me know the Airflow version you have installed. Can you update your python version to 2.7.14?

Comment: @kaxil Thanks for your reply. I successfully installed Airflow following steps on this link: http://site.clairvoyantsoft.com/installing-and-configuring-apache-airflow/

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you have installed a wrong package. `airflow` was renamed to `apache-airflow` from 1.8.1. The website you used has outdated docs.

Please install using the following command

```
export AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE=yes
pip install apache-airflow
```

This should install 1.10.0 which is the latest stable version and resolve your issues.